# Rotativa.WkhtmltopdfDriver An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I am getting following exception on staging server:

```
   [Exception]
   Rotativa.WkhtmltopdfDriver.Convert(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String switches, String html) +975
   Rotativa.WkhtmltopdfDriver.ConvertHtml(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String switches, String html) +51
   Rotativa.ViewAsPdf.CallTheDriver(ControllerContext context) +1310
   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.BuildPdf(ControllerContext context) +250
   Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +422
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>
    b__19() +173
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>
    b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>
        b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
        System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
        System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>
            b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
            System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
            System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
            System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
            System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
            System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>
                b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
                System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
                System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
                System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
                System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
                System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651188
                System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

following code is working fine on my local machine:

```
return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("Order", all) { FileName = "Sample.pdf" };
```

I tried the steps mentioned in [Rotativa PDF generation working locally but not on IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112349/rotativa-pdf-generation-working-locally-but-not-on-iis-7), but didn't help.

Thanks

Comment: You can find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112349/rotativa-pdf-generation-working-locally-but-not-on-iis-7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotativa PDF generation working locally but not on IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112349/rotativa-pdf-generation-working-locally-but-not-on-iis-7)

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am experiencing a similar issue, and the linked question does not help...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same unhandled ex, i found the reason in my deploy.
you need to grant write access to rotative directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!